# How do I close a dialog in another component from Material-UI in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have a modal that have a component inside.
I want to close the modal from that component.

I got a component that have:

```
<Modal open={modalClients} onClose={handleCloseModalClients}>
   <div className={classes.paper}>
      <ClientsTable />
   </div>
</Modal>
```

It is possible to close the modal inside ClientsTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `handleCloseModalClients` is what closes the modal, so you should just need to pass it into ClientsTable and call it somehow. For example, if you have a button in ClientsTable:

```
<Modal open={modalClients} onClose={handleCloseModalClients}>
   <div className={classes.paper}>
      <ClientsTable onCloseModal={handleCloseModalClients} />
   </div>
</Modal>

const ClientsTable = (props) => (
  // Not sure what the inside of ClientsTable looks like, but
  // it should have something you can attach the handler to:
  <div>
    <button onClick={props.onCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://material-ui.com/api/modal/ , you can control opening and closing the modal through the `open` prop in the  component.

Therefore, you can define a state variable in your modal component
`state = { open: false }`

and a function to close it `closeModal = () => { this.setState({ open: false }); }`

and you can pass closeModal function as a prop to the child component inside the modal

`<ClientsTable closeModal={closeModal} />`. Then you can trigger the closeModal function wherever you want inside the `<ClientsTable>` component.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7nc1p

Comment: In your example it closes regardless. All you have to do is click anywhere outside the window. How do you make it so it stays opened and only closes when you click close? My example is having the opposite issue. It stays open but when you click Close it stays open (even though the setOpen(false) function is being called). It's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `open={modalClients}`, and assuming your `modalClients` must be in a state. You can set this state to `false` to close the `modal` from your `ClientsTable` component like,

```
const ClientsTable = props => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={props.hideModal}>Hide</button>
  </div>
);
```

And your modal should look like,

```
<Modal open={this.state.modalClients}>
    <div className="">
       <ClientsTable hideModal={() => this.setState({ modalClients: false })} />
    </div>
</Modal>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-bouman-9czqp?fontsize=14)